# Why is rounding done like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

Why is Python rounding like this?

```
>>> 1.12345678901234567890
1.1234567890123457
>>> 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
0.00011001100110011001
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that, done

Comment: It's not to do with rounding, it's to do with [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: OK (Damn those snippets.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at how floats are handled, and what limitations they have. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html is a Python specific explanation.

In your particular example, Python chooses to use a representation that has a limited number of digits (depends on the Python version). Internally, different float values may share the same (rounded) representation.